# What ammo does Diggle use?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

Just wondering what ammo Diggle uses. I assumed it to be rubber bullets, but rewatching season 3, I see the "Arrow Cave" contains guns. Is Oliver ok with Diggle shooting real bullets to incapacitate and not kill?  This is what I've taken from it.

Comment: They make several comments throughout the show about using Tranquilizer bullets/darts. Earlier on John had used real bullets, but as Team Arrow moved away from killing he switches to the darts-bullet things. I can look for some references/quotes to turn this into a real answer though. There are also some comments about Argus agents using tranquilizer guns. I know in Season 5, about halfway through, after Spoiler
>! Oliver breaks up the team. 
John mentions something like, "we don't have access to our gear, I don't have my tranq bullets"

Comment: Ah right thank you, Have up voted your comment because i am re watching before season 6 only on ep 8 of season 3 again.